# Python script in C# application - IO problems

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

I am trying to embed famous speedtest-cli.py (speedtest.net client) in my C# application, so I could display the output either in the console or in a texbox.

So far I tried following:

```
class PythonSpeedTest
{    
    private String path = @"c:\pythonSpeedTest.py";

    public void runPython() {
        var py = Python.CreateEngine();
        var scope = py.CreateScope();
        var paths = py.GetSearchPaths();
        paths.Add(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib");
        py.SetSearchPaths(paths);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        py.Runtime.IO.SetOutput(ms, new StreamWriter(ms));          
        try
        {
           var output = py.ExecuteFile(path, scope);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {             
            Console.WriteLine("Python collapsed" + ex.Message);
        }
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        var sr = new StreamReader(ms);
        var result = sr.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

The application seem to run the script, but
1. it doesn't wait until it finishes, and 
2. I couldn't make it display any output from python

Ideally I need to be able to wait until the python completes the test; capture and output results into either console or TextBox, or if I could just capture all the output - that would be fantastic.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Are you sure the script is running OK? Set py.Runtime.IO.SetErrorOutput(stream, writer) too so you can see any error.

Comment: Thank you!!! Gotta try that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright!!! after beating my head of a wall for a couple of days I've finally figured it out. First, I didn't have to set any streams in order to get an output from python. Here is the code:

```
class testPython
{
    public void runScript() {
        String path = @"c:\pythonSpeedTest.py";
        var source = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);           
        Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine py = Python.CreateEngine();
        Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptScope scope = py.CreateScope();
        var paths = py.GetSearchPaths();
        paths.Add(@"c:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib");
        py.SetSearchPaths(paths);
        try { 
            py.Execute(source);
        }catch (Exception ex){
            Console.WriteLine("Error occured in python script\n"+ex);
            Console.ReadKey();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

The important thing was to set paths for python engine. The main problem was that I've been running the script in canopy pressing play button(sorry I'm quite a noob), but in the script itself I've never got to simply call main(). Once I've added it - the script was nicely executed under my C# application. Getting data will be easy now.

Hope this gonna save someone some time!